# iOS crashes with function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1]

Tags: iphone, swift2

I am working on project where I select a button and the address book pops up on another view controller with a table view. Issue is that the app crashes on the phone but not in the simulator.

The code from the first view is here:

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
import Parse

class MainPageViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var btnAddress : UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Overview"
        btnAddress.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func getAddressBook (sender : AnyObject){


        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("AddressController", sender: self);
    }


    @IBAction func MyVideosClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    }



    @IBAction func RecordButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
            println("captureVideoPressed and camera available.")
            var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera;
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie!]
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            println("Camera not available.")
        }




    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {
        let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL!
        let pathString = tempImage.relativePath
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        })
        // save video to library
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathString, self, nil, nil)
        var videoData = NSData(contentsOfFile:pathString!)
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

        var dataPath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myalbum")


        if (!(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(dataPath)))
        {
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(dataPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: nil)
        }

        var dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy-HH:mm:SS"
        var now = NSDate()
        var dateStr = dateFormat.stringFromDate(now)
        //        var getImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("/SavedFile.mov")

        var videopath = dataPath + "/" + dateStr + ".mov"
        var success = videoData?.writeToFile(videopath, atomically: false)
        if((success) != nil)
        {
            println(videopath)
            performSegueWithIdentifier("VideoList", sender: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            println("Not Saved")
        }
    }



    @IBAction func leftSideButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        var appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        appDelegate.drawerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Here is the code for the second view:

```
import UIKit
import AddressBookUI
import AddressBook
import MessageUI
import CoreLocation


class AddressController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,LocationDelegate, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate {


    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var Locality : String = "";
    var contactsArray = NSMutableArray();
    var contactList = NSMutableArray();
    var contactNumberArray = NSMutableArray();
    var indexPathArr = NSMutableArray();
    var isLocation : Bool = true;
    // let addressBookRef: ABAddressBook?;
    var addressBookRef: ABAddressBookRef?
    var titleArray : NSArray = ["#","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
    var sectionDictionary =  NSMutableDictionary();
    var errorMessage : String = "";





    @IBOutlet weak var tblContacts : UITableView?;

    func createAddressBook(){
        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &error).takeRetainedValue()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        self.locationManager.delegate = self

        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();

        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization();


        var b = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Send", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "sendMessage:")


        var image = UIImage(named: "settings.png")
        image = image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
        var settingBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "LocationChange");
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [settingBtn,b];


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tblContacts?.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell");



        switch ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus(){
        case .Authorized:
            println("Already authorized")
            createAddressBook()
            /* Access the address book */
        case .Denied:
            let alert = UIAlertView (title: "SmsPush", message: "Denied access to address book. Go to Setting->Privacy->Contacts to enable Contact access!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok");
            alert.show()
            return;


        case .NotDetermined:
            createAddressBook()
            if let theBook: ABAddressBookRef = addressBookRef{
                ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(theBook,
                    {(granted: Bool, error: CFError!) in

                        if granted{
                            println("Access granted")
                        } else {
                            println("Access not granted")
                        }

                })
            }

        case .Restricted:
            let alert = UIAlertView (title: "SmsPush", message: "Access restricted", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok");
            alert.show()

            println("Access restricted")
            return;

        default:
            let alert = UIAlertView (title: "SmsPush", message: "Other Problem", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok");
            alert.show()

            println("Other Problem")
            return;
        }


        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


        contactsArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBookRef).takeRetainedValue() as! NSMutableArray




        for contactObject in contactsArray{

            let contactName  = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(contactObject).takeRetainedValue() as String;
            contactList.addObject(contactName);

        }
        let ansArray = sorted(contactList,{ (s1, s2) in
            return s1.localizedStandardCompare(s2 as! String) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
        })

        contactList = NSMutableArray(array: ansArray);


    }



    //TableView Methods

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return titleArray.count;
    }

    func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]! {
        return self.titleArray as [AnyObject];
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
        return index;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return titleArray.objectAtIndex(section) as? String;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF beginswith[c] %@",titleArray.objectAtIndex(section) as! String
        )
        var sectionArrayList : NSArray = contactList.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
        sectionDictionary.setValue(sectionArrayList.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray, forKey: titleArray.objectAtIndex(section) as! String)
        return sectionArrayList.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell = tblContacts!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell;

        var str = "\(indexPath.section)-\(indexPath.row)";
        if(indexPathArr.containsObject(str)){
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark;
        }else{
            cell.accessoryType = .None;
        }

        var sectionTitle: String = titleArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as! String
        var sectionContacts: NSArray = sectionDictionary.objectForKey(sectionTitle) as! NSArray

        cell.textLabel?.text = sectionContacts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String;
        return cell;

    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        let oldCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath);

        var sectionTitle: String = titleArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as! String
        var sectionContacts: NSArray = sectionDictionary.objectForKey(sectionTitle) as! NSArray

        for contactNames in contactsArray{

            if(sectionContacts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String == ABRecordCopyCompositeName(contactNames).takeRetainedValue() as String?){
                var str = "\(indexPath.section)-\(indexPath.row)";
                if(oldCell!.accessoryType == .Checkmark){

                    if(indexPathArr.containsObject(str)){
                        contactNumberArray.removeObject(contactNames)

                        indexPathArr.removeObject(str);
                        break;

                    }
                }else{
                    if(indexPathArr.count >= 3){
                        let alert = UIAlertView (title: "SmsPush", message: "You can select maximum of 3 recipients", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok");
                        alert.show()
                        return;

                    }

                    contactNumberArray.addObject(contactNames)
                    indexPathArr.addObject(str);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData();
        println("\(indexPathArr.count)");
    }

    //AddressBook functions

    func promptForAddressBookRequestAccess() {
        var err: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil

        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef) {
            (granted: Bool, error: CFError!) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if !granted {
                    println("Just denied")
                    self.displayCantAddContactAlert()

                } else {
                    println("Just authorized")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func openSettings() {
        let url = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
    }

    func displayCantAddContactAlert() {
        let cantAddContactAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Cannot Add Contact",
            message: "You must give the app permission to add the contact first.",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)
        cantAddContactAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Change Settings",
            style: .Default,
            handler: { action in
                self.openSettings()
        }))
        cantAddContactAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(cantAddContactAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // Send Message functions
    @IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {


        if(indexPathArr.count>3){
            let alert = UIAlertView (title: "SmsPush", message: "You can select maximum of 3 recipients", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok");
            alert.show()
            return;
        }else if(indexPathArr.count==0){
            let alert = UIAlertView (title: "SmsPush", message: "No recipients are selected to send message", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok");
            alert.show()
            return;
        }else{


            var messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

            if (!MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
                let alert = UIAlertView (title: "SmsPush", message: "Simulator does not support Messaging.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok");
                alert.show()
                return;

            }

            if(Locality == ""){
                Locality = "Unavailable"
            }
            if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("LocationValue") != nil){
                isLocation =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("LocationValue") as! Bool;
            }
            if(isLocation){
                messageVC.body = "This is a default Message and My location is \(Locality)";
            }else{
                messageVC.body = "This is a default Message and My location is Unavailable";
            }
            var numberArray = NSMutableArray();
            var  numberString : String = "";
            var i : Int = 0;
            for phoneObject in contactNumberArray{

                var phoneNumber : ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(phoneObject, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
                var tempNumber : String = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumber, 0).takeRetainedValue() as! String;

                numberArray.addObject(tempNumber);
            }

            if(numberArray.count==1){
                messageVC.recipients = ["\(numberArray.objectAtIndex(0))"];
            }else if(numberArray.count==2){
                messageVC.recipients = ["\(numberArray.objectAtIndex(0))","\(numberArray.objectAtIndex(1))"];
            }else if(numberArray.count==3){
                messageVC.recipients = ["\(numberArray.objectAtIndex(0))","\(numberArray.objectAtIndex(1))","\(numberArray.objectAtIndex(2))"];
            }
            messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

            self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
        switch (result.value) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled.value:
            println("Message was cancelled")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        case MessageComposeResultFailed.value:
            println("Message failed")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        case MessageComposeResultSent.value:
            println("Message was sent")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    //Location related functions

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        errorMessage = "";
        if(manager.location.coordinate.latitude != 0 && manager.location.coordinate.longitude != 0){
            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    println("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                if placemarks.count > 0 && placemarks != nil {
                    let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                    self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
                }else {
                    println("Error with data")
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


        if(placemark.subLocality != nil){
            Locality = placemark.subLocality
        }else if(placemark.locality != nil){
            Locality = placemark.locality
        }else if(placemark.administrativeArea != nil){
            Locality = placemark.administrativeArea
        }else if(placemark.administrativeArea != nil){
            Locality = placemark.country
        }else{
            Locality = "Unavailable";
        }

        println("\(Locality)");



    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

        errorMessage = "Please enable Location Service for SmsPush";
        println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)

    }

    func locationCheck(isEnabled: Bool) {
        if(isEnabled){
            isLocation = true;
        }else{
            isLocation = false;
        }
    }

    func LocationChange(){
        // self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LocationViewController")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LocationViewController", sender: self);
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

I really don't see why the app is crashing out at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the crash log?

Comment: have you importet the frameworks?